# Jetpack Compose - Detect size constraint applied through Modifier

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I detect **inside** of my composable **what** height constraint was attached to it via the modifier?

```
Column1 {
    Text("abc")
    Text("abc")
}
Column2(Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
    Text("abc")
    Text("abc")
}
Column3(Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
    Text("abc")
    Text("abc")
}
```

I want the `Text` (or other possible `Composable`) to have a different behaviour depending on whether the height of the `Column` was not specified, was specified and it is fixed, or was specified and is set to `fillMaxHeight`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BoxWithConstraints` so you can get min/max width or height or `Constraints` to check if your Composable has fixed or bounded width/height.

For instance this is a dynamic box i use to set dimensions based on size i got from another input so i can make it fit to screen no matter which ratio my required dimensions has.

```
   BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(120.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        val size = gradientColor.size
        val contentWidth = size.width
        val contentHeight = size.height
        val contentAspectRatio = contentWidth / contentHeight

        var boxHeight: Float = constraints.maxHeight.toFloat()
        var boxWidth: Float = boxHeight * contentAspectRatio

        if (boxWidth > constraints.maxWidth) {
            boxWidth = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat()
            boxHeight = (boxWidth / contentAspectRatio)

        }

       val boxWidthInDp: Dp
       val boxHeightInDp: Dp
       with(LocalDensity.current) {
         boxWidthInDp = boxWidth.toDp()
         boxHeightInDp = boxHeight.toDp()
       }

      Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(boxHeightInDp)
            .width(boxWidthInDp)
            .background(brush, RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
       )
}
```

I made a sample that how values are returned in different scenarios from BoxWithConstraints

```
 @Composable
fun BoxWithConstraintsExamples() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier) {

        BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow)) {
            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight"
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight")
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(200.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
        ) {

            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth, maxWidthDp: $maxWidth\n" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight")
        }


        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .widthIn(200.dp)
                .heightIn(200.dp)
                .background(Color.Magenta)
        ) {

            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight")
        }

    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Yeah, somehow I overlooked what `BoxWithConstraints` has to offer. I limited myself to `min/maxHeight` and `constraints.min/maxHeight` for some reason. It seems that `minHeight` and `maxHeight` are only equal for `fillMaxWidth` and `height(x.dp)`. And to differentiate between these two cases I should use `constraints.hasFixedHeight`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `fillMaxHeight`*

Comment: Fixed returns whether min value is equal to maxValue. When you set fillMaxHeight for instance min and max are equal to each other but also this is when you set a fixed height either you should also do a onSizeChanged on parent to check if this maxHeight is equal to parent's.

Comment: You're right. Thankfully, hasFixedHeight is enough for my case.